# Finding unique combinations that fulfill a given set of conditions

Tags: kotlin, filtering, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to find the unique combinations that fulfill the given criteria, sorted by cost.
An example:

```
Criteria: [A, B, C, D]
Entities: [
   E1 = (costs = 5, covers = [A, B, E]),
   E2 = (costs = 5, covers = [C, D]),
   E3 = (costs = 2, covers = [B, C]),
   E4 = (costs = 1, covers = [D]),
   E5 = (costs = 5, covers = [B, D]),
   E6 = (costs = 3, covers = [B, D]),
   E7 = (costs = 0, covers = [E])
]

Expected output (cost to combination): [
  (8, [E1, E3, E4])
  (10, [E1, E2])
  (10, [E1, E3, E6])
  (12, [E1, E3, E5])
]
```

While language doesn't really matter to me, I've set up an example in Kotlin to get started easily:
https://pl.kotl.in/V93dnrvbF

I'm currently working on applying a critical path algorithm to find the 'cheapest' solution, but ideally I'd get a collection of *'all'* possible solutions, ordered by cost, as I need to weigh cost other criteria further down the line in the application, meaning the cheapest solution here might not be the end result.

Note: by 'all' I mean all 'sensible' results, e.g. (8 -> [E1, E3, E4]) but not (8 -> [E1, E3, E4, E7]). All criteria need to be met in the resulting combination, but overlapping in covered criteria is allowed.

Context:
I don't expect the entities list to be very large in reality (0~20), but there's likely to be a lot of of overlap in the covered criteria. I've tried to include this in the example. My application is written in Kotlin.

Comment: What if two different combinations of entities add up to the same cost? They wouldn't be able to both be added to the map since the keys must be unique

Comment: Ah, good catch! Seems I was too focused on the example - I've updated the question to now expect a list of Results, with possibly the same costs.

Comment: By thinking about it quickly. If you eventually need all sensible solutions, then you can't really optimize too much - you have to traverse through all combinations that only makes sense. DFS with cutting out unnecessary edges should be fine here. I think finding the best solution could be done much quicker - by using some variation of Dijkstra. Each unique set of conditions is a node and adding a new entity is an edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full working example that I came up with

```
data class Entity(val costs: Int, val covers: Set<String>, val name: String) {
    override fun toString() = name
}

data class Result(val cost: Int, val entities: Set<Entity>) {
    override fun toString() = "($cost, $entities)"
}

val E1 = Entity(5, setOf("A", "B", "E"), "E1")
val E2 = Entity(5, setOf("C", "D"), "E2")
val E3 = Entity(2, setOf("B", "C"), "E3")
val E4 = Entity(1, setOf("D"), "E4")
val E5 = Entity(5, setOf("B", "D"), "E5")
val E6 = Entity(3, setOf("B", "D"), "E6")
val E7 = Entity(0, setOf("E"), "E7")
val entities = setOf(E1, E2, E3, E4, E5, E6, E7)

fun findUniqueCombinationsSortedByCost(criteria: Set<String>, entities: Set<Entity>): List<Result> {
    val matches = find(criteria, entities)
    return matches?.map { set -> Result(set.sumOf { it.costs }, set) }?.sortedBy { it.cost }
        ?: emptyList() // Implementation
}

fun find(criteria: Set<String>, entities: Set<Entity>): Set<Set<Entity>>? {
    val reduced = entities.filter { e -> e.covers.intersect(criteria).isNotEmpty() }
    if (reduced.isEmpty()) return null
    if (reduced.size == 1) {
        return if ((criteria - reduced.first().covers).isEmpty()) {
            setOf(reduced.toSet())
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
    val result = mutableSetOf<Set<Entity>>()
    for (i in reduced.indices) {
        if ((criteria - reduced[i].covers).isEmpty()) {
            result.add(setOf(reduced[i]))
        } else {
            val results = find(criteria - reduced[i].covers, reduced.subList(i + 1, reduced.size).toSet())
            if (results != null) {
                for (sets in results) {
                    result.add(setOf(reduced[i]) + sets)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}

fun main() {
    println(
        findUniqueCombinationsSortedByCost(
            criteria = setOf("A", "B", "C", "D"),
            entities = entities
        )
    )
}
```

I'm not sure if my algorithm is very efficient but I believe it gets the job done. It prints

```
[(8, [E1, E3, E4]), (10, [E1, E2]), (10, [E1, E3, E6]), (12, [E1, E3, E5])]
```